# git returning to a commit and again get all together

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-commit

I have commits like

```
12345
12346
12347
```

I want to get back tgo `12345` and work on this I will add new commits `23456`, `23457`, `23458` etc

then I may need to get `12345, 12346, 12347 and 23456, 23457, 23458` all together

Is this possible, what should be my steps to achieve this?

Comment: What does "get all together" mean here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want all the commits the current one's and old one, but for now I want to push only `12345` and `23456, 23457, 23458` and not `12346`, `12347` latter I will decide if I will push `12346` and `12347` or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert a Git repository to a previous commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try creating a new branch from the `12345` commit:

```
git checkout -b new_branch 12345
```

Then make your new commits `23456`, `23457`, `23458` on top of this branch.  So, your two branches now look like this:

```
old_branch: 12345 -- 12346 -- 12347
                  \
new_branch:          23456 -- 23457 -- 23458
```

If you want to later bring one set of commits from one branch into the other, you may try merging or rebasing.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a new branch starting from the commit 1234

```
git checkout -b newBranchName <SHA of the starting commit>
```

Then work on this branch and make your commits [23456, 23457, 23458 ....]
and after that you can merge the old and new branches to get the rest of the commits [12346, 12347..] as follows

```
git merge <Base branch name>
```

Now all of your work is on the new branch